# import statemets in Scala

Tags: eclipse, git, scala, import

I look now on the github repository of Spark Github. In the class [ALS.scala](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/master/mllib/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/ml/recommendation/ALS.scala) I try to understand how the import statements are organized. If I do a new Project in Scala and try to do the import statements in my owner Scala class, I can do the next import:

```
import java.{util => ju}
import java.io.IOException

import scala.collection.mutable
import scala.reflect.ClassTag
import scala.util.Sorting
import scala.util.hashing.byteswap64
```

Anyway, if I try to do a Spark import (for example param):

```
import com.github.fommil.netlib.BLAS.{getInstance => blas}
import org.apache.hadoop.fs.Path
import org.json4s.DefaultFormats
import org.json4s.JsonDSL._

import org.apache.spark.{Dependency, Partitioner, ShuffleDependency, SparkContext}
import org.apache.spark.annotation.{DeveloperApi, Since}
import org.apache.spark.internal.Logging
import org.apache.spark.ml.{Estimator, Model}
....
```

I got an warning message:

> object {apache, gizhub, json4s} is not a member of package org

I have download a Spark package from the Github repository on my local machine. After I took a look, I found some orders local on my hard disk. For example in the repository:

```
/home/usr/spark/mllib/src/main/scala
```

I have

```
/org/apache/spark/ml/param
```

My question is, how I can organize the import of this folder in my Scala program? Sorry, I completely newcomer in Scala and can't understand currently the import organization in Eclipse for Scala...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are a newcomer to scala  I would recommend using SBT to manage your dependancies esp as you import new libraries into your scala projects

1. Download Eclipse Scala IDE from scala-ide.org
2. Unzip it somewhere
3. Download  and install SBT from scala-sbt.org and set SBT_HOME to root of the installation
4. Download Spark from  spark.apache.org/downloads.html
5. Unzip it somewhere and set SPARK_HOME env variable root of unzipped file
6. Download 64 bit winutils.exe from https://github.com/steveloughran/winutils
7. Unzip the folder from Github and install it somewhere
8. Set HADOOP_HOME env variable to path where winutile.exe is residing.
   9 decide on project root location say C:\myFirstProject
9. Add sbteclipse plugin (https://github.com/typesafehub/sbteclipse) to SBT by creating a plugins folder to project root and add the followin line to it:

   addSbtPlugin("com.typesafe.sbteclipse" % "sbteclipse-plugin" % "4.0.0")
10. Open sbt from command prompt and type eclipse to ensure plugin is working.
11. manually create the basic folder structure to the project root:

    src/
      main/
        resources/
           
        scala/
           
        java/
           
      test/
        resources
           
        scala/
           
        java/
12. Create a build.sbt file and add the following lines of code to it to support apache spark:

    lazy val root = (project in file(".")).
    settings(
    name := "MyFirstProject",
    version := "1.0",
    scalaVersion := "2.10.4"
    )
    libraryDependencies ++= List(
    "org.apache.spark" %% "spark-core" % "1.3.0",
    "org.apache.spark" %% "spark-sql" % "1.3.0",
    "org.apache.spark" %% "spark-hive" % "1.3.0",
    )
13. This names your project, gives it a version and forces it to use a specific version of scala and also add in dependancies to support spark.

If you require more info I can add to this thread, hope this helps.
Paul.

Comment: thank you very much. I have done already some of your points. Your guide looks very promising. I'm going to do all of your points. Thanks

Comment: some small question, I have already Hadoop installation with path definition in .bashrc (I use ubuntu). Can I pass the steps 6 and 7? I can also give complete list of my installations. The main problem is only Scala

Comment: If you need more let me know ;-) I too was a newcomer to Scala/Spak at one stage!

Comment: If you intend to write files to HDFS and you are running on linux I recommend installing Hadoop. but to keep life simple just populate your RDD/DataFrames from local file copy. If you want to populate the RDD/DF from HDFS then install a single node cluster, so Short answer is yes if not using HDFS

Comment: No, this is only for windows based machines to "Emulate HDFS"

Comment: Thank you very much, currently I execute your steps. Probably will come back later. Thank you very much!

Comment: I am missing steps 14 for some reason. (I dont know why its not being rendered, it avail on editor!?) .. Basically this steo is around setting up the SBT scala file system, v important for you. here is the link...http://www.scala-sbt.org/release/docs/Directories.html.  Basically from project root create a src folder and put in a main and test sub folder. in each sub folder create a scala folder.

Comment: Thank you, step 14 is currently a little bit far away :-)